# libRestKit.a can't find when install RestKit

Tags: iphone, restkit

I followed the https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-in-Xcode-4.x
Checked http://www.raywenderlich.com/13097/intro-to-restkit-tutorial
I tried every thing. 
The libRestKit.a is still red. And "#import " still shows: 'RestKit/RestKit.h' file not found.
How should I do? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally solve it. 
I made a mistake on the Header Search Paths setting. 
The correct one is: "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers". 
I made a mistake on the format of '"'.